# Error while Importing data from .SHP files to spatialite using OGR2OGR

Tags: shapefile, export, ogr2ogr, spatialite, import

I was trying to import data from files provided here http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france.html
 specifically http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/languedoc-roussillon-latest-free.shp.zip

I'm using OGR2OGR, I ran the command

`ogr2ogr append -f SQLite db.sqlite gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.shp -dsco SPATIALITE=YES`

The error I have are

> ERROR 1: sqlite3_step() failed:   gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.GEOMETRY
>   violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed] (19)
>   ERROR 1: ROLLBACK transaction failed: cannot rollback - no transaction
>   is active ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 2026 from layer
>   gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.
>
> ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed translation
>   of layer gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1 (use -skipfailures to skip errors)`

The corresponding spatialite tables are empty so it seems importing failed.

I have searched for solutions and it seems the Geometry column should be made lowercase.

I'm not sure about any solution, since I'm using SHP files. Is there a possible fix?

Note that many other SHP provided in the ZIP file linked above are converted without any issue. This issue happens for several SHP files.

Comment: Its possible the spatial reference is not recognized. You may have to update spatial references in the DB, so that the SRID is recognized.

Comment: Probably the infamous polygon/multipolygon thing. Add `-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and have a new trial. I am sure that this question is duplicate of some other.

Answer (score 2):

user30184 was right

The generated db.sqlite must be removed for appends to work.

`ogr2ogr -append -f SQLite db.sqlite gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.shp -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -dsco SPATIALITE=YES`

I had a python script add all .SHP without any other problem.